# Magento2: how to remove all cart's items from controller?

Tags: magento2, cart, controllers

Please, how can i **remove all cart's items from controller**?

```
namespace Demo\Demo\Controller\Demo;


class Demo extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{


    public function execute()
    {
      //Codes for removing all cart's items
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

First inject the `Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` in your constructor:

```
protected $cart;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
) {
    $this->cart = $cart;
    ...
}
```

Then in your `execute` method you can call:

```
$this->cart->truncate();
```